# Discord/PHP - Assign user role

Tags: php, json, curl, discord

Is it possible, using PHP/Discord API to assign a role to a user?
I currently use OAuth2 for my website visitors to register with Discord. I would then later want to assign the registered website users with a role on a discord server when an admin have reviewed their membership, and I've already configured a bot that have been granted the required permissions on the server.

I have been looking at the documents - but unfortunately they do not really give me the dummy-proof guidance I need. https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#modify-guild-member

Could I do this with Curl maybe?

Answer (score 1):

https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member-role
You can make a cURL call to this API-endpoint, passing a bot token who has the MANAGE_ROLES permission. Here is a code snippet:

```
$authToken = "bot_token";
$guildid = "guild_id";
$userid = "user_id";
$roleid = "role_id";
$url = "https://discordapp.com/api/v6/guilds/" . $guildid . "/members/" . $userid . "/roles/" . $roleid;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
        'Authorization: Bot '.$authToken,
        "Content-Length: 0"
    ),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "PUT",
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);

//It's possible to output the response at this place for debugging, so remove the comment if needed
/*
print $response;
print "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($response));
print "</pre>";
*/
curl_close($ch);
```